# Is there anyway to extract column name for the value equals 'X' in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, measure

My first ever question on this forum. I am relatively new to Power BI and would really appreciate support from the experts in the community.

I am trying to extract the column names for each values of 'X'. I need to look at columns B to J.
Is there a way to do this in power BI.

Appreciate any help. I have attached a screenshot to help understand, let me know if you need more information.

Many Thanks
Azhar

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebLrk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your data looks like this:

| ES No. | ENCL | TYPE | ELEC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 |  |  | X |
| 0002 |  |  | X |
| 0003 | X |  |  |

For the sake of demonstration I've simplified it a bit.

From this, you want to **unpivot your columns**. It's performed in PowerQuery :

1. Go in PowerQuery (*Transform Data*) in the ribbon.
2. In your table, selection columns B to J.
3. In the ribbon, *Transform* tab, choose *Unpivot Columns*.

Your new table looks like this :

| ES No. | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | ENCL |  |
| 0001 | ELEC | X |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 0002 | ELEC | X |

Then, you can create a measure to return the `Attribute` value for each `ES No.` where the value is an X. We'll assume there is only one X per `ES No`.

```
XCol =
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Table[Attribute]),
    Table[Value] = "X"
)
```

[image: The result]

Note, you can avoid getting a value in the Total lines by tweaking the measure.

Comment: Thanks Jeremie L for your help.